# Querying two tables with Wild Card

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

Hello Gurus.

```
        SELECT 

        Hardlines_PTI.PTI, 
        Hardlines_PTI.[Product Line] as Product_Line,
        TT_Data.CASE_ID as TT_ID,
        TT_Data.STATUS as TT_Status

        FROM Hardlines_PTI CROSS JOIN TT_Data

        WHERE

        TT_Data.SHORT_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%' +Hardlines_PTI.PTI+ '%'

        ORDER BY Hardlines_PTI.PTI
```

This is the query that am currently using and not getting any output.

Am trying to get the list of PTI from TT_Data table using PTI as a wildcard to figure out if it is present in the TT_Data.Short_Description column.

Please let me know what am doing wrong here.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s the reason i used the comma-separated list of tables is because they both dont have anything in common for me to join it on.

Comment: Then you should use a `CROSS JOIN` .....

Comment: @marc_s thank you for the suggestion ill use cross join going forward :)

Answer (score 1):

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT p.PTI, p.[Product Line] as Product_Line, p.CASE_ID as TT_ID,
       d.STATUS as TT_Status
FROM Hardlines_PTI p JOIN
     TT_Data d
     ON d.SHORT_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%' + p.PTI + '%'
ORDER BY p.PTI;
```

However, this should produce the same output as your query.  If there is none, then here are some possibilities:

- There are no matches.
- One or more of the columns have "hidden" or "synonymous" characters.  This would depend on the character set.
- You have case-sensitive collations, in which case you can just wrap the two sides in `lower()`:

  ```
   ON LOWER(d.SHORT_DESCRIPTION) LIKE '%' + LOWER(p.PTI) + '%'
  ```

Comment: the reason i didnt use ON in my query is that both the tables dont have anything in common. I ran your query and am not  getting anything its still executing :S

Comment: @GopinathSekar . . . They do have something in common, just not an equality condition.  Perhaps you should ask another question focused on performance.